# BIOS not loading

Tags: bios

I have ASUSk42f laptop, core i3-430 m.

When the hard disk is connected in the machine (as it typically should be), after pressing the power button nothing is shown on the screen (but the power led is on)!

However, if I remove the HDD and power on, then the Bios appears. When I plug any solid state drive in (with an OS installed) then everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you loading up from a pendrive or a hard drive (and does the pen drive work)?

Comment: when I plug the hdd nothing works. but when I remove HDD and plugin any solid state drive then everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

95% of the time when a computer comes into my shop with this problem I end up replacing the Hard Drive and I suspect this is what you will end up doing too.

Things you can try to diagnose:

- Plug your hard drive in as a slave to another machine and run chkdsk
- If you have another known good drive you can try booting your laptop from that

This seems pretty straightforward though, when you plug the drive in it doesn't work and when you take it out, it does work. Sounds like the drive.

Comment: ok. I am not an expert. Your answer seems to be correct. But I can't understand one thing. BIOS is a stand alone program. Then why the HDD causing it trouble to load the BIOS??

Comment: @DebobrotoDas Im not 100% certain why at least the bios doesnt show but my understanding of this has been that the bios does load in the backround but the faulty hard drive somehow keeps the screen from displaying anything. If anyone knows more about why this happens feel free to correct me if im wrong

Comment: @DebobrotoDas: Most likely the drive is not responding to the BIOS and the BIOS is willing to wait forever.

Comment: @DebobrotoDas Probably the drive, but if your BIOS have an option to set if your drive is IDE/RAID/ACHI you might want to try changing those settings.